# Spring Boot creates new JSESSIONID on each request

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, httpsession, jsessionid

Spring Boot application runs on https://localhost:8080 and front-end (Angular) app runs on https://localhost:4200. On each request new JSESSIONID gets set/created as if HTTP session engine does not recognize JSESSIONID it has just set for previous request. But when I start serving front-end app as static content from Spring Boot app (which means same port for Angular app) everything works fine.

**UPDATE 1:** so far I have tracked that this happens because Request object get recycled because this code return false
[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 2**: I now see that "cookie" header like this one is not present in the request when font-end runs on different port.

```
cookie = SLG_G_WPT_TO=en; SLG_GWPT_Show_Hide_tmp=undefined; SLG_wptGlobTipTmp=undefined; JSESSIONID=6C59D1FE6310EE1E141FD96236D9218A
```

When this code is run:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked that even though the browser showed me (in `Cookies` tab) that `JSESSIONID` cookie was present it actually was not sent with the request. I did not notice that `Cookie` header was not present in the requests. I am adding screenshot where a) `Cookies` tab is present and if opened shows `JSESSIONID` which gave me the idea that the cookie is being sent and b) where you can see that `Cookie` header is present in the correct request:
[image]

Why `Cookie` header was not present? Because even though the configuration for `CORS` was correct on `Angular` side:
[image]
but HTTP interceptor's registration was commented in the AppModule:
[image]